# Multiply association to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am working on this code:

```
render json: User.find(params[:id]).to_json(
      :include => 
      {
        :user_quests => { :inlcude => { :quest }, :only => { :id } }, 
        :user_skills 
      },
      :except => 
      { 
        :authentication_token, 
        :email 
      }
  )
```

It results in a `SyntaxError`. The only working code I currently have is:

```
render json: User.find(params[:id]).to_json(
      :include => 
      [
        :user_quests, 
        :user_skills 
      ],
      :except => 
      [ 
        :authentication_token, 
        :email 
      ]
  )
```

But I need to pass further parameters to **only one** of the associations to perform a nested `include`. The other one (`:user_skills`) should be fetched the same way as in the working code. How do I do that?

Comment: By "not working as expected" you probably mean "doesn't work at all", right? The first snippet is syntactically incorrect, a hash is expected to have key-value pairs.

Comment: @D-side yes it doesn't work, I was doing it based on this documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json, how it should look like?

Comment: Hey, that's Rails 2.3.8 docs :D So to clarify: you want to include **two** associations, one of them with some parameters and one without them. Is that right?

Comment: yes, exactly, btw so what should I use with rails 4?

Answer (score 1):

This code results in a syntax error, because you don't use collections properly. An array (`[]`) is a list of values, whereas a hashmap (or simply hash, `{}`) requires key-value pairs.

In `to_json`'s context an array of associations:

```
[
  :user_quests, 
  :user_skills
]
```

...is roughly equivalent to a hash of associations mapped to empty option hashes:

```
{
  :user_quests => {}, 
  :user_skills => {}
}
```

Having performed that transformation, you can selectively add options wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is solution which works for me and is compatible with Rails 4:

```
render json: User.find(params[:id]).as_json(
      include: 
      { 
        user_quests: 
        { 
          include:  
          { 
            quest: 
            {
              only: :_id 
            }
          }
        },
        user_skills:
        {

        }
        },
      except: [:authentication_token, :email]
  )
```

Comment: **Rails** 4. There's no Ruby 4 just yet =) And, actually nothing significant to this question seems to have changed. On Rails 2 your former code wouldn't work as well.

Comment: `gem list` gives me `rails (4.0.2)` so I called it Rails 4, maybe it is mistake but I think it is readable. `to_json` in this RoR version is deprecated so I changed it to `to_json`. I think that now it is ok. Best.